# Can I convert a smart group to a static group by editing the db directly?

Tags: smartgroups

We have a bunch of smart groups that a lot of other smart groups rely on. I'd like to turn these former groups into regular groups and then generate them once a day, to improve performance. But deleting them and reconfiguring all the other groups with the replacements will be quite fiddly, so I'm wondering if I can convert them.

Has anyone tried this? Can I just edit civicrm_group to remove the:

- saved_search_id
- where_clause
- select_tables
- where_tables

? Just wondering if there are any gotchas I need to be aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately **NO**, updating saved_search_id to NULL will actually convert it to normal group but no contact's will get added into this group since for smart group the contact are calculated from civicrm_group_contact_cache table which is rebuild periodically and for normal group its from civicrm_group_contact which is static. So you will need to first rebuild the contacts for a group and then move data from cache to static table like

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_group_contact (group_id, contact_id, status)
SELECT group_id, contact_id, 'Added' FROM civicrm_group_contact_cache 
  WHERE group_id IN (1);
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Cool - that's what I was hoping! I'll be generating the group once a day from a script. Just wanted to check that removing the saved_search_id was all I needed to stop it being treated as a smart group. Thanks!